# How to apply foreach array function in for below code for selected action

Tags: javascript, laravel

This is the code of the file `app.js` in Laravel. I want convert multiple or condition of `selectedAction` into JavaScript array function. I am new to JavaScript so I don't know.

```
$('#page_hr_applicant_edit .applicant-round-form').on('click', '.round-submit', function() {
  let button = $(this);
  let form = $(this).closest('.applicant-round-form');
  let selectedAction = $(this).data('action');
  if (selectedAction == 'confirm' || selectedAction == 'send-for-approval' ||
    selectedAction == 'onboard' || selectedAction == 'approve') {
    if (!form[0].checkValidity()) {
      form[0].reportValidity();
      return false;
    }
  }
  form.find('[name="action"]').val(selectedAction);
  button.prop('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('disabled');
  form.submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try see the following code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button.data-form").on("click", function() {
    var action_form = $(this).attr('data');
    $("form").attr('id', action_form);
    $("form").attr('data', action_form);
    $("form#" + action_form).submit(function(event) {
      //event.preventDefault();
      console.log("co:" + action_form);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <button class="data-form" data="form-1">Click form 1</button>
    <button class="data-form" data="form-2">Click form 2</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define array with all possible values of actions, Instead of `or` you can use `indexOf` method which will return `index` of your action. If index is `0` or greater than `0` means the item is found in array else it is not found in array. Below is the sample code for converting the `or` logic to `array`

```js
const actions = [ 'confirm', 'send-form-approval', 'onboard', 'approve' ];
if(actions.indexOf(selectedAction) >= 0) {
  // Action is found in array
}
else {
  // Unknown action i.e. Action is not found in array
}
```